# Getting error in bluemix ERS ERRORCODE -4461 SQLSTATE D42815 though the DW is available in Dash DB.

Tags: ibm-cloud, dashdb, embeddable-reporting

I am getting an error ERRORCODE -4461 SQLSTATE D42815 while trying to create a report specification on bluemix ERS. 
I used Cloudant NOSQLDb and Dash db. Also Node.js as run time. 
I followed the https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i5CmLLEORkM tutorial.
Please suggest if I am missing something.

Thanks
-Rawi

Comment: You need to provide us more details, with the information above it is going to be difficult to help. I found this link with the explanation for the error code you mentioned http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21622381. Please take a look and see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks Alex, I will check and keep you posted about it. Meanwhile, Do I need to change/update anything in the node.js --> app,js or package.json - like adding some code etc, pls?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need make any changes to the application other than binding the two services (ERS + Cloudant) to your application. Could you provide a bit more context about which step you're hitting the error?